# Create and add an incremented key to a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am new to python and I have been unable to find an answer through various google searches. Essentially I am trying to add a new key to a dictionary through a function. I need the function to create a unique key that is incremented each time it passes through a loop. The value for these keys will be input as an object that is already filled out.

Example of what I am looking to do:

```
dict = {}
looper = 0
While looper < 100:
    dict[newkey1] = value
    looper += 1
```

Ultimately I need the outcome to be a dictionary as follows:

```
dict = {newkey1 : value1, newkey2 : value2, newkey3 : value3, ...}
```

The values will be created by a mathematical function and passed into the value slot from earlier in my script.

I'm not sure if there is even an answer to my question. I may have structured my program incorrectly from the start.

EDIT**
Hi Everyone, thank you so much for your answers. After reading through the answers below and implementing some of them, I think I have a better understanding of what I am looking for.

In short here is what I'm doing: I have a class called window. window has 4 different properties. I want the user to input those properties into a new object. After the object has been created, I want to store the object within a dictionary as a key. The value will be set as 0 to start. I will then update that value based on an irrelevant mathematical equation. What I need to do is have a new incremented object created as such:

```
win1 = Window(var1 = input("please input var1:", etc, etc, etc).
```

win1 is what I need to have incremented and saved into a dictionary each time.
This will just run in the terminal for now, as I have yet to teach myself GUI.

Essentially It will operate as such:

```
#user enters win1 and variables.
more_win = input("Do you have another window to enter?")

while more_win == "yes":
   # this is where I dont know what to do
   # program needs to generate a new object that is incremented
   # and then stored within a dictionary having the value of that newly 
   # incremented key be 0 EX(win1: 0, win2 : 0, etc, etc)
win2 = Window(var1 = input(...), etc, etc, etc)
```

I hope this makes sense! I hate to be asking a dumb question, I just don't know what to google here.

Comment: What are the values of `newkey1, newkey2` etc?

Comment: You can use numbers like those stored in "looper" directly as keys.

Comment: The values for `newkey1, newkey2`, etc. can be set to 0 or any integer, as they will be updated later in the program based upon an irrelevant math equation.

Comment: Michael, so what I understand now, is that I should be able to create a new key by doing something like this:  `def new_key(): increment = 1 dict["newkey" + str(increment)] = 0 increment += 1`

Answer (score 0):

As a first pass this is what you're looking for:

```
def add_value(dx: dict, new_value) -> dict:
  max_key = int(sorted(dx.keys())[-1])
  dx[max_key + 1] = new_value
  return dx
```

There are some caveats here, though:

- It assumes that all the keys in the dictionary can be parsed as ints. If not, it will fail.
- It sorts on each call, which could be time expensive.

If you could guarantee that the dictionary does not have other keys being added to it, you probably don't need a function:

```
original_dictionary: dict = ...
sorted_dictionary = {k: original_dictionary[k] for k in sorted(original_dictionary.keys())}
...
// Whenever you add a key
new_idx = sorted_dictionary.keys()[-1]
sorted_dictionary[new_idx] = new_value
```

This is because in Python 3.7+ dictionaries retain their key sort order.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to generate a unique key every time, you could do the following, by import python uuid package:

```
import uuid

dict = {}
looper = 0
while looper < 100:
    key = uuid.uuid4()
    dict[key] = value
    looper += 1

# output: 
# {UUID('b7feb1c6-f070-4424-968a-f73438bbf7a8'): Value 0,
# UUID('524db4db-aa2a-41af-b794-827f896b8101'): Value0 1,
# UUID('b1a67189-531f-4590-bd03-8d66f44b46b3'): Value0 2,..}
```

Otherwise if you want to create a unique key that is incremented each time, you could do the following by make looper as key:

```
dict = {}
looper = 0
while looper < 100:
    key = looper
    dict[key] = value
    looper += 1
```